# How can i zoom the background to the center point without using background position in css?

Tags: javascript, html, css, function, zooming

Html

```html
<div class="board"></div>
```

JS Drag function

```js
var mouseProperties = {
    mouseState: false,
    prevX: null,
    prevY: null,
}

var debugMode = {
    appDebug: false,
    isDrawEnabled: false,
    isAnchorEnabled: false,
    isEraserEnabled: false,
    fpsAlreadyRunnin: false,
    eraserRadius: 20,
}

// triggers when the mouse is pressing
document.addEventListener("mousedown", () => {
    mouseProperties.mouseState = true;
});

// and triggers when mouse isn't pressing
document.addEventListener("mouseup", () => {
    mouseProperties.mouseState = false;
    mouseProperties.prevX = null;
    mouseProperties.prevY = null;
});

//theres a mouse down eventlistener and an if state to check if mouse is pressing and if true then
//it will run the if below (debugmode is binded to a button in my html file it's not that important)
if (!debugMode.isDrawEnabled && !debugMode.isEraserEnabled) {
            const currentX = e.screenX;
            const currentY = e.screenY;
        
            if (mouseProperties.prevX !== null && mouseProperties.prevY !== null) {
                const deltaX = currentX - mouseProperties.prevX;
                const deltaY = currentY - mouseProperties.prevY;
        
                const lastPosX = parseInt(board.style.backgroundPositionX || 0);
                const lastPosY = parseInt(board.style.backgroundPositionY || 0);
        
                const anchedElements = document.querySelectorAll('.anch');
                const bypassElements = document.querySelectorAll('.bypass');

                anchedElements.forEach(nailed => {
                    const anchX = parseInt(nailed.style.left || 0);
                    const anchY = parseInt(nailed.style.top || 0);
                    nailed.style.left = `${anchX + deltaX}px`;
                    nailed.style.top = `${anchY + deltaY}px`;
                });
        
                board.style.backgroundPosition = `${lastPosX + deltaX}px ${lastPosY + deltaY}px`;

                bypassElements.forEach((el) => observer.observe(el))
            }
        
            mouseProperties.prevX = currentX;
            mouseProperties.prevY = currentY;
        }
```

JS Zoom function

```js
const board = document.querySelector(".board")
var boardScale = 40

// unzoom
function unzoom() {
    if (boardScale > 10) {
        boardScale -= 5
    } else if (boardScale < 10 || boardScale == 10) {
        boardScale = 10 
    }

    board.style.backgroundSize = `${boardScale}px ${boardScale}px`
}

// zoom
function zoom() {
    if (boardScale < 70) {
        boardScale += 5
    } else if (boardScale > 70 || boardScale == 70) {
        boardScale = 70 
    }

    board.style.backgroundSize = `${boardScale}px ${boardScale}px`
}
```

This is where I'm having the problem. Normally I'd prefer using `background-position: center center` but in my project I'm using it to drag the boards background around so I can't use it. I tried some math thing etc. but they didn't work either. I tried to scale the board. It worked very well when I zoomed the board but not when I made it unzoom.

When I drag the board around it changes the center of the background then when i zoom in and the zoom was on that point. So I tried to subtract the board width and height with the background position but I couldn't do it.

Comment: I can give the website link if you need to test further.